# Testcafé - getting content of invisible <input>'s value attribute

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, testing, testcafe

I need to get the value of an `<input>`, specifically the stuff that is held inside its value attribute.

However, the `input` is not visible, so that seems to be a problem for testcafé.

Does anyone know how to work around that? Is there a special option you can use with the `Selectors` to make it work?

Thanks for helping me out, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it, simply declare a Selector like this `let yourInputs = Selector('input[type="hidden"]')`, this will get all hidden `inputs` and return a NodeList which you can iterate over in your test.

If you want to be more specific and select over an ID or name, do it like @lumio.

Then you can access the value in your test run with an `await yourInputs.value`.

Comment: Also, if you want to execute JavaScript within the Selector, you can use it as follows: `var yourVar = Selector( () => { "your logic here" })` - this allows you to make changes to your otherwise quite static selection. Just return a string, Node or NodeList after you're done. Here you can actually use the querySelector as well!

Answer (score 5):

I guess you mean a hidden input element as in `<input type="hidden" />` and you want to receive the value before you're sending it to your Node application. You can use `querySelector` for this.

```js
console.log( document.querySelector( 'input[name=test]' ).value );
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="hello world" />
```

---

For [TestCafé](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) you got the [`Selector`-constructor](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors.html) which creates a selector.

As fweidemann14 pointed out, you can do the following:

```
const hiddenInputs = Selector( 'input[type="hidden"]' );
```

Comment: Of course this is working, but I want to use the capabilities of Testcafé, not just plain js ;)

Comment: Figured it out, your js was actually quite helpful, gonna upvote for getting me on the right track man ;)

Comment: @fweidemann14 awesome! I misinterpreted `TestCafé`. Learned something new today. I updated my answer, but I'd would accept your answer instead!

Comment: Great, hopefully this will help some people in the future! This is why I love SO ;)